# A Cryptic clue; an all encompassing question

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Oh I dismay. My life is infinitesimal, the universe so huge and everything is amiss! Won't you help me find meaning? I won't make it another $(Year)_8$. The weeks would just drag on! Wont you help me find an answer? Something to help explain it all?

Same riddle with highlighted keywords

> Oh I dismay. My **life** is infinitesimal, **the universe** so huge **and everything** is amiss! Won't you help me find meaning? I won't make it another $(Year)_8$. The weeks would just drag on! Wont you help me find **an answer**? Something to help explain it all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the answer is

> 42

Explanation

> "I won't make it another $(Year)_8$. The weeks would just drag on!"
>
> There are 52 weeks in a year, so $(Year)_8$ = $52_8$ = 5*8+2 = 42.
>
> I think all the other sentences just refer to trying to find the answer to the question of the universe etc etc